Implementation of a close button for a component within a dialog
I have a component A that should normally be displayed without a close button. However, when I open component A in a dialog, I want to add a Close Button to close the dialog.
How can I implement this behavior in Angular? Is there an elegant way to determine if the component is open in a dialog so I can add a Close Button accordingly?
Thanks in advance for your assistance!
Here is my code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-p4pfnr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fb%2Fb.component.ts
FULL CODE:
popup html
<form [formGroup]="form" class="">
  <h1>App A</h1>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      type="email"
      formControlName="email"
      placeholder="Ex. pat@example.com "
    />
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-button type="button" color="primary">Save</button>
</form>

popup ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './a.component.html',
  styleUrl: './a.component.css',
})
export class AComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }
}

calling ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AComponent } from '../a/a.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './b.component.html',
  styleUrl: './b.component.css',
})
export class BComponent {
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  public openDialog() {
    this.dialog
      .open(AComponent, {})
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
}

calling html
<button (click)="openDialog()" mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button">
  Open Dialog
</button>


Yes we can use the data property of the second argument of open method. we set a property fromPopup as true and then read it on our component!
I use the angular decorator @Optional so that even if we use this component outside of a popup, we still will not get dependency injection error for trying to get MAT_DIALOG_DATA
b ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AComponent } from '../a/a.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AComponent],
  templateUrl: './b.component.html',
  styleUrl: './b.component.css',
})
export class BComponent {
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  public openDialog() {
    this.dialog
      .open(AComponent, {
        data: { fromPopup: true },
      })
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
}

b html
<button (click)="openDialog()" mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button">
  Open Dialog
</button>

<app-a />

a ts
import { Component, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './a.component.html',
  styleUrl: './a.component.css',
})
export class AComponent {
  form!: FormGroup;
  fromPopup = false;

  constructor(
    @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { fromPopup: boolean }
  ) {
    this.fromPopup = !!data?.fromPopup;
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }
}

a html
<form [formGroup]="form" class="">
  <h1>App A</h1>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      type="email"
      formControlName="email"
      placeholder="Ex. pat@example.com "
    />
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-button type="button" color="primary">Save</button>
</form>
<button *ngIf="fromPopup" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">
  shows only for popup!
</button>

Stackblitz Demo

If you know you will have multiple cases like this one in your code, you can create a generic dialogHandler, and call it whenever you want to show a component in a dialog. Let's call it modalHandlerComponent:
modalHandler.component.ts
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialogHandler',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatDialogModule, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './dialogHandler.component.html',
  styleUrl: './dialogHandler.component.css',
})
export class DialogHandlerComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { component: Type<any> }) {}
}

It will get the component you want to inject thanks to MAT_DIALOG_DATA which is how you give data to a Material UI dialog.
modalHandler.component.html
<h2 mat-dialog-title>A dialog with component injection. You can inject a title via data if you want.</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="data.component"></ng-container>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close button</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>

The component will then display the component thanks to the ng-container.
b.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AComponent } from '../a/a.component';
import { DialogHandlerComponent } from '../dialogHandler/dialogHandler.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './b.component.html',
  styleUrl: './b.component.css',
})
export class BComponent {
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  public openDialog() {
    this.dialog
      .open(DialogHandlerComponent, {
        data: {
          component: AComponent,
        },
      })
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
}

Here we are injecting the component we want to display in the dialog into the dialogHandler component through MAT_DIALOG_DATA.
And there you go! You can call that component with the one you want to display in the data parameter.
Stackblitz Demo
